# how to insert data into table using django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new in django, and I am creating table in postgresql. I want to perform insert, update and delete operation using django. I want creating followng code.

Models.py

```
class Publisher(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=50)



def __str__(self):

    return ' '.join([

        self.name,
        self.address,


    ])
```

viwes.py

```
 def pramod(request):
     if 'pname' in request.GET and request.GET['pname']:
         p1 = request.GET['pname']
     if 'address' in request.GET and request.GET['address']:
        p2 = request.GET['address']
     books = Publisher(name=p1,address=p2)

 return render(request, 'Publisher.html',{'books': books})
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have already? And why have you not read the tutorial?

Comment: Where is the issue? If the issue is that you know too little about django to perform a simple operation then you should learn the language first.

Answer (score 18):

You need to create an instance of the model class (Publisher in this case), instantiate it with the appropriate values (name and address) and then call [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save), which composes the appropriates SQL `INSERT` statement under the hood.

```
book = Publisher(name=p1, address=p2)
book.save()
```

I recommend you read the [model docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save).

Answer (score 6):

This is the minimum code you need. Then you can add fields verification, or whatever you need:

```
publisher = Publisher(name=p1,address=p2)
publisher.save()
```